# Correct format for the keys in the PhpStorm's license server

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm through the license server, and it took a while for me to find out the correct format to put the keys I bought in it. In the e-mail I received from jetbrain the keys was in the format:

```
===== LICENSE BEGIN =====
XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
===== LICENSE END =====
```

But the license server doesn't like them, it complains:

```
Possible reason: missing 'User Name: ....' line at the beginning of pasted text
```

(answering my own question in 3..2..1..)

Comment: Why not authenticating using your Jetbrains account? This way you don't have to copy paste your license key, I do it this way.

Comment: We are 5, we all need PhpStorm sometimes but not always so we bought only 3 licenses. PhpStorm is installed on all PCs and using the license server allows us to use it where we want (up to 3 instances at the same time). Would authenticating using the Jetbrains account allow us to do the same?

Comment: As long as you use account from which you bought the license, I don't see why it shouldn't. Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: @MuhammedM. After a long conversation with the JetBrains support I'm now sure that for our needs the only working solution is using the license server. All other ways to assign licenses bound them to specific users and that wont work for us.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, thanks for letting know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format is:

```
User name: foo foo foowithspaces
===== LICENSE BEGIN =====
XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
===== LICENSE END =====
```

Where the `User name:` can contain spaces.
In the e-mail I received the whole name line wasn't even there.

**EDIT**
This is valid for the old license server, the new one (since 2016) works differently.